# table border missing due to multi row

Tags: tables, border

Please how can i get proper table borders of table shown below. please see my code 
[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu} 
\usepackage{multicol,graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>
{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Extreme Learning Machine(ELM) with kernel classifier having reduced dimension of feature vectors individual accuracy}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|C{0.5cm}|L{2cm}|l|l|l|l|} \hline
Algorithm & Dimension &  \multirow{ 6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\thead{ADD THESE\\ DIMENSIONS}}}   & Total after Adding Dimensions &Classifier &\multirow{1}{*}{\thead{ Dimension\\Reduction Technique}}             &\multirow{1}{*}{\thead{ Reduced\\Dimension}}&Accuracy \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-8} 
CDF & 4D & & &ELM & \multirow{5}{*}{\thead{Correlation as Dimension\\ Estimator, PCA as \\ Dimension Reduction}} &\multirow{5}{*}{\thead{26 dimensions \\ reduced to\\ 4 dimensions}} &\multirow{5}{*}{\thead{Combine accuracy\\ of 4\\ dimensional reduced\\ Feature Vector\\ is 68\%}} \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}\cline{5-5}
GO & 4D & &\multirow{3}{*}{\thead{4D + 4D + 4D \\ + 7D + 7D= 26D}} &ELM\\ \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
Bilateral & 4D & & &ELM \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
SLDFFO & 7D & &  &ELM\\ \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
SSGSM & 7D & &  &ELM\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- missed vertical lines have nothing with use of `multirow`. there are missing ampersands. consequences are missing vertical lines.

  *note, each rows had to have the one less ampersands as are number of columns*
- it is sufficient in preamble lead each package only ones
- your table is unnecessary complicated and lead to iconsistent looks of table. for example:

  - with changes of column types from `{|l|l|C{0.5cm}|L{2cm}|l|l|l|l|}` to `{|l|l|c|C{2.5cm}|c |C{2.5cm}|C{2cm}|C{2.5cm}|}`  and exploit capability of recent `multirow` package, except one all `\thead`s can be removed in table body as well in column headers
  - with removing `multirow` all cells containing one line text become equal height
- considering above suggestion table code become much shorter, cleand and concise

revised table is:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{array} % loaded twice
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}% added, for rothead
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, tabu}%merged in one line
%\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} % not used
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}% in this table is better use this definition

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{DIMENSIONS}
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \centering
\caption{Extreme Learning Machine(ELM) with kernel classifier having reduced dimension of feature vectors individual accuracy}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|C{2.5cm}|c|C{2.5cm}|C{2cm}|C{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
Algorithm
    & Dimension
        &  \multirow{6}{*}{\rothead{ADD THESE\\ DIMENSIONS}}
            & Total after Adding Dimensions
                & Classifier
                    & Dimension Reduction Technique
                        & Reduced Dimension
                            & Accuracy  \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-8}
CDF & 4D    &
                & \multirow{5}{=}{4D + 4D + 4D\\ + 7D + 7D = 26D}
                    & ELM
                        & \multirow{5}{=}{Correlation as Dimension Estimator,
                                          PCA as Dimension Reduction}
                            & \multirow{5}{=}{26 dimensions reduced to 4 dimensions}
                                & \multirow{5}{=}{Combine accuracy of 4 dimensional
                                                  reduced Feature Vector is 68\%}    \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
GO          & 4D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &   \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
Bilateral   & 4D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &   \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
SLDFFO      & 7D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &   \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
SSGSM       & 7D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user2102092, i wonder, why you remove acceptance of my answer? in which aspect the answer suddenly not solve your problem and fulfill your expectation. I like to learn how to better answer on similar questions ...

Comment: Zarko Brother sorry it happened by mistake.. your Answer exactly solved my problem.. thanks again

Comment: @user2102092, and do you intend to repair this mistake :-)?

Comment: Repaired :D :D :-)

Comment: i just clicked over a TICK sign.. is it the way? i am new plz pardon my nonsense

Comment: @user2102092, thank you! happy tex-ting!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the `&`s up to the end of the rows. I took the opportunity to simplify and improve your code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multicol, graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage{makecell, threeparttable, caption}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\settowidth{\rotheadsize}{DIMENSIONS}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Extreme Learning Machine(ELM) with kernel classifier having reduced dimension of feature vectors individual accuracy}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|C{0.5cm}|L{2cm}|l|l|l|l|} \hline
Algorithm & Dimension &
\multirow{7.5}{*}{\rothead{ADD THESE\\ DIMENSIONS}}
& Total after Adding Dimensions &Classifier &\thead{Dimension\\Reduction Technique} & \thead{ Reduced\\Dimension} & Accuracy \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-8}
CDF & 4D & & &ELM & \multirowthead{3.8}{\thead{Correlation as Dimension\\ Estimator, PCA as \\ Dimension Reduction}} & \multirowthead{6}{26 dimensions \\ reduced to\\ 4 dimensions} & \multirowthead{6}{\{Combine accuracy\\ of 4 dimensional reduced \\Feature Vector is 68\,\%} \\ %
\cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}\cline{5-5}
GO & 4D & & \multirowthead{3}{4D + 4D + 4D \\ + 7D + 7D= 26D} & ELM & & & \\ %
\cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
Bilateral & 4D & & &ELM & & & \\ %
\cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
SLDFFO & 7D & & &ELM & & & \\ %
\cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
SSGSM & 7D & & &ELM & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]