# Adding 3 multi-columns upside in a table

Tags: tables, longtable

I have posted this code before. i now want to add two multi columns upside down to the same table jus like i have marked before and after table picture to make my point clear [image: Before nested/upsidedown multicolumn]

[image: After Adding nested/upsidedown multicolum(i need to add multi col where i draw those black boxes)]
Here is my code of picture no 1 i posted

\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{table*}

```
\settowidth\rotheadsize{DIMENSIONS}

\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

    \centering

\caption{Extreme Learning Machine(ELM) with kernel classifier accuracy of 

combine reduced feature vectors whose individual classifier accuracy was low}

    \begin{tabular}{|l|l| c |C{2.5cm}| c |C{2.5cm}|C{2cm}|C{2.5cm}|}

    \hline 

Algorithm

    & Dimension

        &  \multirow{6}{*}{\rothead{ADD THESE\\ DIMENSIONS}}

            & Total after Adding Dimensions

                & Classifier

                    & Dimension Reduction Technique

                        & Reduced Dimension

                            & Accuracy  \\ 

    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-8}

LBP & 4D    &

                & \multirow{5}{=}{4D + 6D + 4D\\ + 3D + 4D = 21D}

                    & ELM

                        & \multirow{5}{=}{Eigenvalue as Dimension Estimator,

                                          PCA as Dimension Reduction}
                            & \multirow{5}{=}{21 dimensions reduced to 

dimensions}
                                & \multirow{5}{=}{Combine accuracy of 9 
dimensional
                                                  reduced Feature Vector is 
again 80\%}    \\

    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}

RGLBP         & 6D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &   \\

    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}

BDIP   & 4D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &   \\

    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}

HOG      & 3D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &   \\

    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}

Combine and reduced     & 4D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &    \\ 

 fv of poor individual  &       &   &   &       &   &   &  \\ 

  accuracy algorithms   &       &   &   &       &   &   & \\  

    \hline

\end{tabular}

\label{table:table6}

\end{table*}
```

Comment: Missing many things to be a compilable code... please provide everything (but not more) needed to be able compile your code...

Comment: you mean packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you not provide compilable mwe, i use [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416357/table-border-missing-due-to-multi-row/416365#416365) for your previous similar question to show principle how to make "multi paragraph" multi row cell. in it "paragraphs" can be separated between itself (only) with `\newline` command. for small vertical space between them seems to be ad  `\smallskip` before `\newline appropriate measure:

```
\multirow{5}{=}{Correlation as Dimension Estimator,
                PCA as Dimension Reduction\smallskip\newline                                        
                Add Multicol here\smallskip\newline  
                Add Multicol here
                }
```

this should be simple to use/add in your table, for mine the complete mwe is:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{array} % loaded twice
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}% added, for rothead
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, tabu}{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}% in this table is better use this definition

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{DIMENSIONS}
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \centering
\caption{Extreme Learning Machine(ELM) with kernel classifier having reduced dimension of feature vectors individual accuracy}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|C{2.5cm}|c|C{2.5cm}|C{2cm}|C{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
Algorithm
    & Dimension
        &  \multirow{6}{*}{\rothead{ADD THESE\\ DIMENSIONS}}
            & Total after Adding Dimensions
                & Classifier
                    & Dimension Reduction Technique
                        & Reduced Dimension
                            & Accuracy  \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-8}
CDF & 4D    &
                & \multirow{5}{=}{4D + 4D + 4D\\ + 7D + 7D = 26D}
                    & ELM
                        & \multirow{5}{=}{Correlation as Dimension Estimator,
                                          PCA as Dimension Reduction\smallskip\newline
                                          Add Multicol here\smallskip\newline
                                          Add Multicol here
                                          }
                            & \multirow{5}{=}{26 dimensions reduced to 4 dimensions}
                                & \multirow{5}{=}{Combine accuracy of 4 dimensional
                                                  reduced Feature Vector is 68\%\smallskip\newline
                                                  Add Multicol here\smallskip\newline
                                                  Add Multicol here
                                                  }    \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
GO          & 4D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &   \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
Bilateral   & 4D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &   \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
SLDFFO      & 7D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &   \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{5-5}
SSGSM       & 7D    &   &   & ELM   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]